# Why doesn't PowerShell Test-Path work with "\\?\" prefix when passing a root-drive path?

Tags: windows, powershell, path

On Windows 10 Test-Path works with any normal valid paths

```
PS C:\> Test-Path E:
True
PS C:\> Test-Path E:\
True
PS C:\> Test-Path E:\test
True
```

But if I use the [long path prefix `\\?\`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) it'll only work when the path points to a subfolder in the drive

```
PS C:\> Test-Path \\?\E:\test
True
PS C:\> Test-Path \\?\E:\
Test-Path : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot process argument because the value of
argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Path \\?\E:\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

PS C:\> Test-Path \\?\E:
Test-Path : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot process argument because the value of
argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Path \\?\E:
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

Why is that and is there any way for it to work for any `\\?\` paths?

Comment: Why would you specify a long path moniker for a short path test? The document you point to specifically states the goal of the moniker and using it without the fully qualified UNC to that folder target is not what that document is stating. You also, have to have long path enabled/configured. This is a file system control not a PowerShell one.

Comment: Furthermore, consider using a single dot [`.`] in place of the question mark [`?`] i.e. `Test-Path \\.\E:\test`. Have a read over some https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file detail.

Comment: Also, you can do something like.... `$z = Resolve-Path "\\?\E:\test\";` followed by `Test-Path $z.ProviderPath;` to get `True` as well.

Comment: @postanote the path is from a function argument that can be long or short, and at some point I need to check whether the path exists or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the reason. There's a note in the documentation for [FindFirstFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) API saying

> Prepending the string `\\?\` does not allow access to the root directory.

So it's likely that `Test-Path` was implemented using `FindFirstFile`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a couple of things that evaluate to `true` while still raising an error.

```
Test-path -literalpath \\?\E:\
True
```

But powershell issues a warning about illegal characters, in reality the output looks like this:

```
PS C:\User\This-User> test-path -LiteralPath \\?\c:\
test-path : Caracteres no válidos en la ruta de acceso. #PC is in Spanish it means: Non valid characters in path
At line:1 char:1
+ test-path -LiteralPath \\?\c:\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\?\c:\:String) [Test-Path], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

True
```

But it returns `True`. Furthermore if you do a `Resolve-path -literalpath \\?\c:` it will return something like this:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\?\c:\
```

Whereas if the drive doesn't exist it will return nothing.

I don't know how to get rid of the warning, but it evaluates to `True` if it exists and to `False` if it doesn't

One idea would be to combine the output of `Resolve-path` after you split the string to `Test-path` but I think you are going this way to use long path names.

Hope this helps a little.

EDIT:

Also I think the correct syntax when working with physical drives in the machine is `\\.\c:\` this will also evaluate to `True`.